# Some questions about the properties of ${f(x,y)= \frac{2x^2y+y^3}{x^2+y^2}}$

Tags: partial-derivative

Determine if the function that is defined as
$\displaystyle{f(x,y)= \frac{2x^2y+y^3}{x^2+y^2}}$,
for $(x,y)\ne (0,0)$, and is $0$ in origo,
is

a) continuous in origo,

b) have partial first derivatives in origo,

c) is differentiable in origo,

d) is of type $C^1$ in any environment around origo.

So for the solutions:

a) I presume that if I want to calculate the partial derivative of f(x,y) at any point away from the origin $(0,0)$, I can use the usual formulas. I would usually use $$\lim _{\left(x,y\right)\to \left(0,0\right)}f\left(x,y\right)=f\left(0,0\right)$$
However, if I want to calculate $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}(0,0)$, I have to use the definition of the partial derivative. Is this true and how would it apply to this specific problem?

b) I think I will get the answer to this if I use the partial derivative formula in a)

c) I know that if a) is true, this one is also true

d) I don't really understand $C^1$, what is the difference from $C^2$ and how does it effect my approach to a solution?

I would really like to understand this, but also learn from a solution. I think that I am on the right way, I just have problems approaching it, or put my thinking into action.